# Local system windows service is throwing Webexception:"Unable to connect to remote server"?

Tags: c#, web-services, service, database-connection

I am working on a windows service to upload data from database to a remote server in C# using visual studio 2012, when I am using a "Local system windows service", it is throwing a webexception:"Unable to connect to remote server". But when I am using "user service", it is sending the data to server successfully. But user service asks the username and password during installation, which I do not want. How can I create a local system service, which can upload data to server without throwing above webexception? I have checked the firewall settings also.

Comment: I guess the remote server wants you to authenticate. You have to solve that...